# How to disable new Chrome search in web feature that opens a side panel?

Tags: google-chrome

[image: I just want the search to pop a new tab like the usual one.]

If anyone knows, please kindly share, I don't know this random new feature's name and I just want my "select text, right click, search in web and pop a new tab" thing back.
thank you

Comment: @Rubén, oh yes this is the same issue..... uh oh i guess it's a duplicate now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also searching for the same. I searched for your title, and the side bar popped up with a google search of "chrome://flags/#side-search" which if you copy and paste then select disable turns that stupid feature off.

PS : don't forget to click relaunch at the bottom after doing this!

Comment: New name of the flag: `chrome://flags/#search-web-in-side-panel`

Comment: This not working for me. I have the flag `chrome://flags/#side-search` set ti disabled, but it is still doing it. The flag `chrome://flags/#search-web-in-side-panel` not exists for me

Comment: Yeah, doesn't appear to be a working solution currently.